# How to read from string until string becomes uppercase?

Tags: python, string, conditional-statements

I'm trying to extract everything before the text becomes uppercase at the letter G and none of the text that comes after.

```py
string = 'abcdefGfecdab'
```

So the goal is to return `'abcdef'`.
I tried a for loop with a nested while loop

```py
for a in string:
   while(a == a.lower()):
      print(a)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't print, concatenate to a result string that you'll return at the end.

You don't need a `while` loop, you need an `if` statement to test the current character. And when the test fails, use `break` to exit the `for` loop.

```
result = ''
for a in string:
    if a.islower():
        result += a
    else:
        break
print(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, using [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```py
from itertools import takewhile

string = 'abcdefGfecdab'

out = ''.join(takewhile(lambda ch: 'a' <= ch <= 'z', string))
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
abcdef
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`itertools.takewhile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile
  
string = 'abcdefGfecdab'

# If you want to print each `char` in one line.
for i in takewhile(lambda x: x.islower(), string):
    print(i)

# If you want to get all chars in one word
res = ''.join(takewhile(lambda x: x.islower(), string))
print(res)
```

Output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
abcdef
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def get_lower_until_upper(strng):
   i = 0
    while strng[i].islower():
        i += 1
    return strng[:i]
```